# Confused about Spring IoC container with Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

I started developing a REST API with Spring MVC.
I deployed it in a Tomcat container and it works like a charm.

As Tomcat is responsible for creating a new thread for each request (please correct me if I'm wrong), I wonder how Spring deals with this to manage the IoC (inversion of control) container.

Example : I have the following service

```
@Service
public class UserService{
    private String username;

    public setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

So basically Spring will create this singleton and make it available for everyone.

If a request comes and sets the "foobar" username, does the "getUsername" call from the next request (from a different user) return "foobar" ?
How Spring manages that situation ?

Regards

Comment: There is a single instance regardless how many threads you have. Spring manages nothing. Sharing singletons **with state** is something you generally shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others have mentioned, by default Spring creates Singleton scoped beans so each thread will see the same class-level state as the other threads. In this case it's a best practice to avoid maintaining class-level state in your applications, and to pass all required data through the app within the method scopes, thus making them thread-safe.

But Spring let's you create new instances of beans per thread if you want it. You can annotate your bean with @Scope("prototype") and you will get a bean instance per thread. The default is @Scope("singleton"). There are several other scopes available if you need them.

Comment: doest it mean that by default I should put the prototype scope on the services ?

Comment: Yes, use prototype scope if you're absolutely sure you want a new instance each time and you want to maintain state within the class/object. With a high number of concurrent threads/users you might see a performance impact with many more instances of the object created. So, it's a trade-off you'll need to make - take a potential performance hit having many more object instances in memory, or redesign your app to avoid maintaining state in the objects, and revert back to using singletons.

Answer (score 0):

By default spring beans are singleton scoped, that means spring creates single instance of the bean and provide same instance to all the threads. Since your bean is stateful(username), the state also will be shared with all the threads, spring does not do any magic there.
So if one thread sets the username "xyz" then the second thread will see it as "xyz".

Answer (score 0):

From the [`docs`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-singleton)

> Only one shared instance of a singleton bean is managed, and all
>   requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition
>   result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring
>   container.
>
> To put it another way, when you define a bean definition and it is
>   scoped as a singleton, the Spring IoC container creates exactly one
>   instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single
>   instance is stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all
>   subsequent requests and references for that named bean return the
>   cached object.